# Is an electron attracted to one of the magnetic poles ...?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

I noted the question above had been posted.  And I wanted to comment, but nay, it was locked out.  However, what of the old 'CRT' tubes, in which magnetic fields are used to steer the electron stream ?  Now I know the 'Electron's' do not get attracted, or repulsed directly to the source of the magnetism, but the magnetic field certainly has an effect.  So if one were to extend the CRT tube to ... well, rather long, would the electron eventually move to, or away from the 'North' or 'South' pole ?

Comment: Actually, in a CRT, magnetic fields are not used to steer the electron stream but rather to focus the electron stream.  Electro-static deflection plates and thus the electric field is used to steer (or, change the direction of deflection) of the electron stream.

Answer (score 1):

An electron, or any charged particle, is affected by the Lorentz Force.  The Lorentz force shows the total force acted upon the charged particle due to the Electric Field and the Magnetic Field.  Since you specifically are interested in the Magnetic Field, I will focus on that.  The Lorentz Force is written in the vector notation as:
$$
\textbf{F} = q \textbf{E} + q \textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}
$$
This equation shows that the Magnetic Force $\textbf{B}$ affects the direction of motion of the charged particle moving at velocity $\textbf{v}$ due to the vector cross product that determines the direction of the force.  If the charged particle is not in motion with respect to the magnetic field then it will feel no force.

This is precisely the Force equation that you would use to compute the trajectory of electrons in a CRT tube affected by both electric and magnetic fields.

About your question though regarding the long CRT.  The question lacks precision about where the magnetic field is located verses the moving charged particle.  If you would like a similar scenario consider the circular motion of a particle accelerator such as LHC, or even a cyclotron.  By properly extending the magnetic fields around the circular track the charged particle can be turned into the circular motion via the affects of the Lorentz Force.  Cyclotrons are similar but the use of the magnetic field is different where the charged particle spirals out in motion rather than maintaining a circular path.

Answer (score 0):

The electron has an intrinsic magnetic dipole moment $\mu$ related to its spin. Therefore,in addition to the Lorentz force, it should also experience a net magnetic force in the gradient of a magnetic field and move in or against its direction depending on its spin orientation.Therefore, an electron should indeed be attracted or repelled by a magnetic pole.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input.  I think I just answered my own question.  (The site suggested refining question, but can't get there easily).  Aurora Borealis.  I hope that answers the question I answered. (Grin).

Charged particles hit the earths magnetic fields and follow those lines to the poles.  I want to thank one of the users who had queried, "How long a CRT" and made me think of a infinite magnetic field, which of course, the only example I could think of is the earth.

So, thanks again for all the input!

Cheers!